# String to Date in Java

Tags: java, date

HI,

I am converting String to Date format. But it returns wrong dates. for example,

```
String startDate = "08-05-2010"; //  (MM/dd/yyyy)
```

I want to convert this to "Date" object like this,   05-JUL-10

How to do that? I tried like this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
scal1.setTime(dateFormat.parse((startDate)));
```

but i am getting    "Unparseable date:" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert a date string of one format to another format, you can use format() and parse() methods of [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class

First you need to parse the string to a date object using parse() method setting the source pattern and then format the date object using format() method setting the target pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date sourceFormatDate = sourceFormat.parse("08-05-2010");
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String destFormatDateString = destFormat.format(sourceFormatDate);
System.out.println(destFormatDateString); // 05-Aug-10
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've left something out, it looks like you're trying to parse it with the wrong format, i.e. you have an mm-dd-yyyy, and you're trying to parse it with the format dd-MMM-yy.  Try a separate date format for what you're parsing from what you're encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(“yyyy-MM-dd”);
String strDate = “2007-12-25″;
Date date = null;
try {

   date = format.parse(strDate);

} catch (ParseException ex) {

   ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format `dd-MMM-yy` you use to parse the string is wrong; the format should be `dd-MM-yyyy`.

```
String startDate = "08-05-2010";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse((startDate));
```

Note that `Date` objects themselves do not have a format: a `Date` objects just represents a date and time value, just like an `int` is just a number, and doesn't have any inherent formatting information. If you want to display the `Date` in a certain format, you'll have to use a `DateFormat` object again to format it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
// output: 08-May-10
```