# Converting string into date type

Tags: java

I have used the `Calendar` class to get the current `Date`. Now I want to convert that date to `Date` format so that it can be stored in database with format `"yyyy.mm.dd"`. I tried to convert this using  `SimpleDateFormat` class

```
        String dateString  = dateText.getText();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy.mm.dd ");
        Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

but  I couldn't  convert into `Date` type.

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411708/string-to-date-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove spaces from the format string

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.mm.dd");
```

Also if your input date has invalid format you might get a parse exception. Better if you put it into `try/catch` block.

Notice, that `m` stands for `minute in hour` but `M` for `month of year`. Make sure you put a valid [format pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

You havent stated what the error is but its unlikely that you want to use a minute field to parse the month. Use uppercase `M`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

get rid of the whitespaces in your pattern

Comment: White space refers to the leading and trailing SPACE character inside the quotes of the format string.