# Convert String to Timestamp in Java

Tags: java

Our customer will send us request including timestamp String likes :
`"2013-10-27T13:00:00.325234Z"`. I will use it to compare  timestamp in oracle database.

how to convert the above String to java.sql.Timestamp?

I can convert it to Date, but Date only has the milliseconds precision.

Should keep the microseconds and timezone. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything?Lets show us

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411708/string-to-date-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java date to sql date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292468/java-date-to-sql-date)

Comment: precision is different, can't find the answer from the provided url

Answer (score 10):

Apart from the T in the middle and the Z at the end, you could pass it into [`Timestamp.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

So you could just have:

```
String line = "2013-10-27T13:00:00.325234Z";
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(line.replace("T"," ").replace("Z",""));
```

This gives a timestamp matching

```
2013-10-27 13:00:00.325234
```

Comment: thanks, but it will keep the Local Timezone not UTC, any ideas to keep the Timezone?

Comment: The java code and oracle is in different time zone, how to compare the timestamp?

Comment: your answer give me some idea

Answer (score 5):

### Java 8

```
    String timestampString = "2013-10-27T13:00:00.325234Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(timestampString);
```

Don’t use the `Timestamp` class if you can avoid it. To save the timestamp from the string, just pass the `Instant` to your `PreparedStatement` using its `setObject` method. It requires JDBC version 4.2 or higher. You probably have that already, or you should be able to get such a driver. You may also pass the `Instant` to a modern JPA implementation.

Parsing works without any explicit formatter because your string is in ISO 8601 format, the format that the modern java date and time classes parse (and also print) as their default.

The `Timestamp` class is long outdated. If you still need a `Timestamp`, for example for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, the conversion is easy:

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(timestampString));
```

### Java 6 and 7

Add ThreeTen Backport to your project (link below). Use the following imports.

```
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
```

Then do:

```
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(timestampString);
    Timestamp ts = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp(inst);
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 4):

This is a Java 8 solution. It relies on the `java.time` library.

```
String isoStamp = "2013-10-27T13:00:00.325234Z";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(
                             isoStamp,
                             DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME );
```

The [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is a date-time object that has a precision of nanoseconds, and includes the offset from UTC. And the [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) is a standard `DateTimeFormatter` format, that understands the `Z` designation and sets it as offset 0 from UTC.

The next step is to use this in JDBC, and Oracle says in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) that the `java.time` objects should be used with the `setObject()` method (rather than `setTimeStamp()`). E.g.

```
stmt.setObject( 1, odt, JDBCType.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE );
```

Note that this may depend on the database and JDBC driver, which should, of course, be up-to-date.

Comment: any idea about java version < 8?

Answer (score 0):

For me the String format was not yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS. So Timestamp.valueOf didn't work. So, I did like this

```
String s = "2017-12-29-05.04.18.104071";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");//Yes, it works without .SSSSSS
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(sdf.parse(s).getTime());
ts.setNanos(Integer.valueOf(s.substring(20)) * 1000);
System.out.println(ts.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

what ever format you have define it in SimpleDate format , convert it to date and then convert it to Timestamp.

```
public static Timestamp stringToTimeStamp(String strTime){
    Timestamp tempTimestamp = null;
    if(strTime!=null && !strTime.equals(""))
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd");//format of date and time you have

        Date parsedTimeStamp = null;
        try {
            parsedTimeStamp = dateFormat.parse(strTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tempTimestamp = new Timestamp(parsedTimeStamp.getTime());


    }
    return tempTimestamp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[with Java8] If the format is strictly specified and you want a robust solution, use `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date into a `java.time.LocalDateTime` that handles fraction of seconds down to the nanos and then you can create the `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String line = "2013-10-27T13:00:00.325234Z";
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(line, dateFormat);
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(time);
    System.out.println(ts);
}
```

prints

> 2013-10-27 13:00:00.325234

Comment: Wrong answer. The `Z` in the string means UTC, but you parse into your local time zone. The correct way is even simpler: `Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(line))`. Using Java 8 date and time classes is a good idea.